# Pubkey authentication not allowing to enter the server

Tags: ssh, configuration, authentication

I'm trying to access my server through SSH using pubkey authentication, but it's not working and I don't understand why. I've been around this same issue for 2 days now.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. All I did was update the operating system, creating a user called "webdev" with sudo permissions. Then I configured the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/00-server-init.conf` file which is included by the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

**/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/00-server-init.conf:**

```
Port 2405
Protocol 2

PermitRootLogin no
AllowUsers webdev

PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

**/etc/ssh/sshd_config**:

```
# $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

I now have two terminal windows opened: one inside the server (through ssh) and the other one on the local computer. I created a ssh-keygen on my local computer (Macbook) and copied the `key.pub` content (using vim) to the other terminal window to a `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. The permissions for that file are now 777 (I'm for anything right now).

But when I set the `PasswordAuthentication` to `no` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/00-server-init.conf` file, I am not able to enter using public key authentication. I get a

```
@.ssh : ssh webdev@IP -p 2405
webdev@IP: Permission denied (publickey).
```

error. Even though I have

And I have to replace `PubkeyAuthentication yes`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the server side sshd logs for errors / warnings, because typically  permissions are checked for among others ~/.ssh/authorized_keys files and when you say that *"permissions for that file are now `777`"*   that is usually considered insecure

Comment: Try to add option `-vvv` to view ssh connection in verbose mode.

Comment: Are you referring to the home directory of `webdav` (as per `/etc/passwd`) when you wrote `~`?

Answer (score 2):

> The permissions for that file are now 777 (I'm for anything right now).

## THAT WILL NOT WORK.

The permissions of that file (and the folder containing it) should *not* allow world writes. That would allow any user to add their own key to log in as that user.

If you actually checked the logs, you'd probably see a error message complaining that the file is world writeable. Run `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys; chmod 700 ~/.ssh`.

The *first* thing you should do when something doesn't work is read the logs. In this case, that's probably `/var/log/auth.log` and `journalctl -u sshd`.

Comment: Better `chmod 0600`. It's octal number and to avoid issues it's better to prefix with 0; there is no point for it to be executable either. Also, aren't permissions of the `~/.ssh` directory itself checked too?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Agree.

Comment: The _file_ should be mode 600 (or at most 644) but the directory should be 700 (or at most 755) so that you can still edit (or just check) the files. @NikitaKipriyanov+ the argument to `chmod` is always treated as octal (if numeric rather than ugoa+-=rwx format). Many other Unixy/Cish things do use leading zero for octal, but not this one. The fourth digit in chmod, if used, controls the setid&sticky bits; see the man page.

Comment: Yes, and I think I have right to have this kind of a professional deformation as I still work with HP-UX daily, since our vendor failed to migrate some services away from it during last upgrade :). I read the manual *prior* to writing that comment and still convinced that, while GNU's utils are smart in many ways, this additional digit is not much to type, better is to be safe than to be sorry and this smartness corrupts us sometimes. And yes, it's in line with C number literals (try to compile a program  `int main() { return 09; }` and hope for the error message to contain the word "octal").